# Import User and Group with Powershell in AD from a csv file

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, import, active-directory

I'm pretty new in Powershell.

I was working in a cloud environment creating an Active Directory with some users and groups and had to close the server in which I was working. 
In order to reproduce and have a completely identical enviromment, I used this code

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Csv -Path ExportUsers.csv
```

and also

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Csv -Path ExportGroups.csv
```

did with my code an export of ALL users and groups from the Active Directory using Powershell in order to export ALL info of the users and groups.

Now, I have create a VM with a new Active Directory in my laptop and at least I created the same domain name I had in the cloud (just to start in a closes as possible way).
I'm not able to **import now all groups and all users** **WITH ALL PROPERTIES there are in the file**. I saw in several threads that someone created some scripts inserting inside all params they need from the file. In reality, I'd like to have all info of the user so I'm trying the easier way to import all data without going to say exactly the fields I need (I need everything!)
The export was pretty simple so I hope the import should be the same.

The header columns of my csv file in regard to **users** is this:

> AccountExpirationDate,"accountExpires","AccountLockoutTime","AccountNotDelegated","adminCount","AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption","BadLogonCount","badPasswordTime","badPwdCount","CannotChangePassword","CanonicalName","Certificates","City","CN","codePage","Company","Country","countryCode","Created","createTimeStamp","Deleted","Department","Description","DisplayName","DistinguishedName","Division","DoesNotRequirePreAuth","dSCorePropagationData","EmailAddress","EmployeeID","EmployeeNumber","Enabled","Fax","GivenName","HomeDirectory","HomedirRequired","HomeDrive","HomePage","HomePhone","Initials","instanceType","isCriticalSystemObject","isDeleted","LastBadPasswordAttempt","LastKnownParent","lastLogoff","lastLogon","LastLogonDate","lastLogonTimestamp","LockedOut","logonCount","logonHours","LogonWorkstations","Manager","MemberOf","MNSLogonAccount","MobilePhone","Modified","modifyTimeStamp","msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes","msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed","Name","nTSecurityDescriptor","ObjectCategory","ObjectClass","ObjectGUID","objectSid","Office","OfficePhone","Organization","OtherName","PasswordExpired","PasswordLastSet","PasswordNeverExpires","PasswordNotRequired","POBox","PostalCode","PrimaryGroup","primaryGroupID","ProfilePath","ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion","pwdLastSet","SamAccountName","sAMAccountType","ScriptPath","sDRightsEffective","ServicePrincipalNames","SID","SIDHistory","SmartcardLogonRequired","State","StreetAddress","Surname","Title","TrustedForDelegation","TrustedToAuthForDelegation","UseDESKeyOnly","userAccountControl","userCertificate","UserPrincipalName","uSNChanged","uSNCreated","whenChanged","whenCreated"

and this is just an entry of an user

> ,"9223372036854775807",,"False",,"False","0","0","0","True","mydomain.com/Users/Guest","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection",,"Guest","0",,,"0","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM",,,"Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain",,"CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com",,"False","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection",,,,"False",,,,"False",,,,,"4","True",,,,"0","0",,,"False","0",,,,"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","False",,"3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM",,"0","Guest","System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity","CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com","user","b3cdb85f-aa85-41e8-a36a-1e9cabb03bf2","S-1-5-21-1277972300-3555916100-1183092696-501",,,,,"False",,"True","True",,,"CN=Domain Guests,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com","514",,"False","0","Guest","805306368",,"15","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","S-1-5-21-1277972300-3555916100-1183092696-501","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","False",,,,,"False","False","False","66082","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection",,"8197","8197","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM"

and, in a similar way, I have exported all GROUPS, so that now I have a csv with these headers:

> "adminCount,"CanonicalName","CN","Created","createTimeStamp","Deleted","Description","DisplayName","DistinguishedName","dSCorePropagationData","GroupCategory","GroupScope","groupType","HomePage","instanceType","isCriticalSystemObject","isDeleted","LastKnownParent","ManagedBy","member","MemberOf","Members","Modified","modifyTimeStamp","Name","nTSecurityDescriptor","ObjectCategory","ObjectClass","ObjectGUID","objectSid","ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion","SamAccountName","sAMAccountType","sDRightsEffective","SID","SIDHistory","systemFlags","uSNChanged","uSNCreated","whenChanged","whenCreated"

And an example of an entry

> 1,"prestige.com/Builtin/Administrators","Administrators","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM",,"Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain",,"CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=prestige,DC=com","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","Security","DomainLocal","-2147483643",,"4","True",,,,"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","3/21/2014 2:18:22 PM","3/21/2014 2:18:22 PM","Administrators","System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity","CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=prestige,DC=com","group","729af9dd-25ee-448e-a63e-72fa546aa83e","S-1-5-32-544","False","Administrators","536870912","15","S-1-5-32-544","Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection","-1946157056","12711","8199","3/21/2014 2:18:22 PM","3/21/2014 2:00:02 PM"

What should be the best way to import ALL info, using maybe powershell again and that csv, in my new Active Directory? I need to have it as more similar as possible of the AD I had in the cloud.
Thanks everyone for your help: I'm not finding a good way to resolve :-(

Comment: i would prune your CSV exports to use only the data that you want & can use. for instance, i seriously doubt you can use the SID info. [*grin*] ///// also, is there a reason you are not using the MS AD Migration tool? i don't know if it will work in your particular situation ... but if it will, then i would use that.

Comment: Just write a small import script that excludes the problem fields. As above, it's probably refusing to import specific fields which are unique to the AD such as SID.

Comment: Yeah, I was not able to use the Migration Tool due that as prerogative both AD should be talk together. I had to go faster due that my cloud environment was expiring :-(

Comment: So at least I exported everything to be sure I can reproduce the same env to the new AD.

Comment: Do you think I have to write in any case in a script ALL header in the file?
I'd like to use something like "Import everything from the file" without say which colums.Sure I can remove some not useful information in (i mena, some columns), but still remains a lot of columns in the file